# Android Studio - Emulator Stuck On Black Screen

Tags: android

I am not new to android studio, however am having a problem with my emulator. Anything I try to run it runs the emulator frame but just black screens. I have reinstalled android studio and have tried a range of emulators. Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

I have also tried

SDK Update and installing a different image

I have looked at other threads with no luck in finding a solution

[image: What I currently see]

Answer (score 0):

Turn the Emulator on.

[image]

If this doesn't help, then wipe the emulator and create a new virtual device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, sadly neither of these fixed the problem